# How to find dates in the same financial year?

Tags: pandas

My Dataframe looks like this...

```
ECSDate DateOfTransfer  Amount
2011-12-04      2011-05-16 25000
2012-11-10      2011-05-16 3000
2013-02-19      2011-05-21 13750
```

I need to find if the ECS and transfer date is in the same financial year that starts on 1 April and ends on 31 March.

```
If Month is Jan, Feb or march then:
2013-02-19 - 1 year = 2012-02-19 and 2012-04-01 is greater than 2011-05-21 so false

Else:
2012-11-10 start of year is 2012-04-01 and greater than 2011-05-16 so false
```

The expected result would be

```
True
False
False
```

---

Edit:

Something that I tried.

This is 1 year old date:

```
mydf['NEW_DATE'] = mydf['ECSDate'].apply(lambda x: x - pd.DateOffset(years=1))
```

Compare it:

```
pd.to_datetime(mydf['NEW_DATE'].dt.year, 04, 01) < DateOfTransfer
```

---

Edit:

The following statement is correctly returning the True, False values. But how do I apply it to dataframe?

```
pd.Period('2011-12-04', freq='A-MAR') == pd.Period('2011-05-16', freq='A-MAR')

pd.Period('2012-11-10', freq='A-MAR') == pd.Period('2011-05-16', freq='A-MAR')

pd.Period('2013-02-19', freq='A-MAR') == pd.Period('2011-05-21', freq='A-MAR')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydf[mydf['ECSDate'].dt.to_period(freq='A-MAR') == mydf['DateOfTransfer'].dt.to_period(freq='A-MAR')]
```